# Looking for a good C/C++ wavelet library for signal processing

Tags: c++, c, signal-processing, wavelet

Does anyone know of a good C/C++ wavelet library for signal processing?

The signal is float or double valued, not int valued.

Comment: Discrete or continuous wavelet transform? What do you want to do?

Answer (score 22):

Without more information or clarification of what you mean by good (Good for what ?), it is difficult to make any recommendation.

Some C/C++ Wavelet libraries are listed below.

- [Wavelet](http://herbert.the-little-red-haired-girl.org/en/software/wavelet/)
- [Geophysical Wavelet Library](http://users.math.uni-potsdam.de/~gwl/)
- [WvLib](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~kline/wvlib/)
- [wavelet1d](http://code.google.com/p/wavelet1d/)
- [WAILI](http://nalag.cs.kuleuven.be/research/software/wavelets/)
- [GNU Scientific Library or gsl](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Wavelet-Transforms.html) for DWT documentation
- [blitzwave](http://blitzwave.sourceforge.net/)
- [nwave](http://code.google.com/p/nwave/)
- [Wavelet Image Compression Library](http://www.maven.de/code/wavelet/)
- [Kicksey-Winsey](http://justpmf.com/romain/kicksey_winsey/) which features a library called Template Wavelet Library that supports OpenMP

Answer (score 8):

In case you have a high-end gpu (nvidia cuda enabled or from other manufactorer) you can use [cuvilib](http://cuvilib.com/).

Comment: In case you have a high-end gpu (nvidia cuda enabled or from other manufactorer), try to find libraries that exploit the graphics card power for computations. For the kind of algorithms that i guess you are looking for, you will find some really fast libraries.