# C/C++ Wavelet library, non-GPL

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, wavelet, haar-wavelet

Ideally what I'd like to find is something with a simple, straightforward interface to multiple wavelet categories, like the GSL, but which has a license that lets me use it in proprietary software.  The [top answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606458/looking-for-a-good-c-c-wavelet-library-for-signal-processing) lists 10 Wavelet libraries, however all but one are licensed under the GPL, and [the one that isn't](http://www.maven.de/code/wavelet/index.html) seemed a little heavyweight, with the wavelet calculation wrapped up within larger image-processing functionality (which I'm not doing).  In any case I would like to have more options.

I also found [this](http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~ttwong/demo/dwtgpu/), which looks cool, but it presumes a cuda-capable GPU and I can't assume that.

Comment: Just to clarify, LGPL would be acceptable to you?  Also, GPGPU abstraction layers such as OpenCL and CUDA should be able to fallback to the CPU.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes it would.

Comment: So strip out the parts you need from the "heavyweight one", and recompile it.

Comment: @BenVoigt Actually CUDA doesn't work (on Windows) on machines that don't have a CUDA-capable card, you get a 'nvcuda.dll not found' error which can't be corrected by simply supplying the file.  I.e. I think [this situation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594993/emgucv-nvcuda-dll-could-not-be-found) generalizes.

Comment: Well, what about implementing it yourself so? It is not that difficult.

Comment: @Archie Ha ha not if a pro has done it for me--the difference between the 'naive' implementation of an algorithm such as I can produce, and what people like the authors of the GSL et al. can be several orders of magnitude in speed over relevant ranges.  Even for something as simple as matrix multiplication.

Comment: Oh don't underestimate yourself :) If your main business is doing wavelets than do it yourself. And who told you cannot glance into GSL and others source code while implementing yours?

Comment: @Archie: If he's writing proprietary software, his lawyers will be *extremely* clear on the point that he cannot "glance into" the GSL source code while implementing his.

Comment: @user4619 Hi, `info at wavesorter dot com`should reach me.  Post again here if you don't get a response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Found one](https://sourceforge.net/projects/leasy-wavelet/?source=dlp)!  It offers the Apache 2.0 license along with the GPL.  Unfortunately, it only calculates one specific transform ('Lazy transform with lifting') so I would still like to know about more options if there are any.