# How to find continuous wavelet filter bank coefficients in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing, wavelet, filter-bank

I use `cwtfilterbank` to create continuous wavelet filters but this routine just give me frequency response of filters. How can I find filters coefficients?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the filter bank (the filters of all levels of your transform at once) you would get a matrix, where every row (of the same length as the signal) contains the filter at one position.

So the bottom half of the matrix is level 1 (detail coefficients only, you only need half the matrix because of downsampling), the next quarter is level 2 (detail only again) and so on.

For a transform of level `L`, the final `2^(-L)` coefficients are the approximation coefficients at that level. There's some code to do that [here](https://www.programmerall.com/article/2743386743), as an example the matrix of a 3-level Haar transform on a signal of length 16 is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16562005/1793968).

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  actually I look for  continuous wavelet filter bank not discrete wavelet.  Sites you introduced talking about discrete wavelet filter banks.

Comment: That does not exist for the cwt. However you can plot individual wavelets using https://nl.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/cwtfilterbank.wavelets.html -- of you combine all of them in one plot that could be closer to what you want?